# Get records according to Date wise

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

My Table looks like this in SQl Server 2008.

[image: I want to show result as in image]

Please provide the `Linq query` example to get this result as in image.

Comment: Umesh -  It isn't a "Code-For-Me" site, Try something related to GroupBy.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i just need an example to get this type of data from LINQ.

Comment: No idea how to get this type of data. and what search criteria to get the result from google..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var query = from x in MyTable
    group x by x.Date into g
    Select(x => new { x.Message, x.ID , x.RefId, x.Date});
```

Comment: this query will get all the records. but how to group this records acc. to date.

Comment: Or more simply, `from x in MyTable group x by x.Date into g select g` or as a lambda - `MyTable.GroupBy(x => x.Date)`